# Mobile audio upload returning octet/stream

Tags: php, audio, upload, mime-types

On desktop, the upload works correctly, but when I try to upload from a mobile device, it says that the extension is outside the array, and print returns octet-stream, any thoughts? I can't see what could be wrong. I have tried many audio extensions, checked MIME and tested with a few smartphones, no success.

```
if (isset($_POST['submit_atrack'])) {
$fileinfo=PATHINFO($_FILES["audio"]["name"]);
$newFilename=$fileinfo['filename'] . uniqid($usr_idLogged) . "." . $fileinfo['extension'];
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["audio"]["tmp_name"],"atracks/" . $newFilename);
$location = 'atracks/' . $newFilename;

$formatos = array('audio/mpeg', 'audio/ogg', 'audio/mp3', 'audio/*', 'audio/wav');
$tamanho_max    = 500000000; //500 mb


    if (empty($_FILES['audio']['name']))
    {
        $upload_empty = urlencode("empty");
        header("Location:playlist?newtrack=".$upload_empty . "&playlist=" . $selectedPlaylist);
        exit;
    }
    else if (!in_array($_FILES['audio']['type'], $formatos))
    {
        $upload_incorrectformat = urlencode("incorrectext");
        header("Location:playlist?newtrack=".$upload_incorrectformat . "&playlist=" . $selectedPlaylist);
        exit;
    }
    else if (in_array($_FILES['audio']['type'], $formatos)) 
    {
        if($_FILES['audio']['size'] >= $tamanho_max)
        {
            $upload_maxsize = urlencode("maxsizereached");
            header("Location:playlist?newtrack=".$upload_maxsize . "&playlist=" . $selectedPlaylist);
            exit;
        }
        else 
        {
            $atitle = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST['atitle']);
            $atag = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST['atag']);
            $atagcolor = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST['atagcolor']);
            mysqli_query($connection,"INSERT INTO tbl_users_atrack (atrack_title, atrack_path, atrack_tag, atrack_tagColor, atrack_playlistId) VALUES ('$atitle', '$location', '$atag', '$atagcolor', '$selectedPlaylist')");
            $upload_success = urlencode("success");
            header("Location:playlist?newtrack=" . $upload_success . "&playlist=" . $selectedPlaylist);
            exit;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: try inspecting what is posted exactly. print_r($_POST) and print_r($_FILES) might shed some light on what your are receiving and WHY it is outside your predefined types.

Comment: Everything is correct, except the MIME type returning `application/octet-stream`, but the same file, with the same code is identified as `audio/mp3`

Comment: application/octet-stream is just name giving by many environments for a stream of bytes. So it is pretty general. (sometimes attachments without extension are passed like that). Isn't there anything else in $_FILES that gives a hint? like original filename?

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection. You should use prepared statements.